# HTTP GET request Angular returning Object object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a backend server that sends JsonNode object as RestAPI response. and I am doing the following HTTP GET request in Angular:

```
  getReports(): Observable<Report[]> {
return this.http.get<Report[]>(`${this.apiServeUrl}/reports`).pipe(
  tap(reports => console.log(`Fetched reports`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<Report[]>('getReports'))
)
}
```

The problem is that when I do `console.log(reports)` it returns an array of Object object. This is Postman results though:

[image]

Angular does not allow me to apply `map` when I do the `http.get()` request, hence I figured out that if I do the following:

```
  getReports() {
this.reportService.getReports()
  .subscribe(reports => {
    this.reports =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(reports))
    console.log(this.reports)
  })
 }
```

Is the only way that I can obtain my `Reports[]` and do the proper interpolation at my page?

Why am I receiving an Object and why do I need to do that workaround?

Comment: Why exactly is getting an array of objects a problem? What did you _expect_? And what makes you think `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(reports))` changes anything, given you just got `reports` by `HttpClient` parsing JSON? It's worth noting that TypeScript **does not exist** at runtime, the type metadata is erased in compilation, so if you're expecting a class `Report` to be instantiated based on the generic type you will be disappointed!

Comment: @JPV could you provide the actual response of what `${this.apiServeUrl}/reports` return?

Answer (score 0):

I think we are missing information regarding the GET request to the /reports endpoint. Probably the API to which you make the request returns a structure of a type that does not correspond to a list of reports as you expect. Check with postman which type of return do the /reports request and make a post so we have that information as well.